# How to restrict output of following query to only be of datatype number/integer by joining with ALL_TAB_COLS? - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Essentially need the following query to only output a column name of datatype Number/Integer? How would I restrict the output to only a specific data type?

```
select column_name, num_distinct 
from all_tab_col_statistics
where table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
order by num_distinct desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

I'm aware of the fact that doing this involves joining with the ALL_TAB_COLS table but I'm not sure how I would implement this given my current query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS` to `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` as it contains columns' datatypes.

If you want to include several tables, a simple way is to use then `IN` clause and name all tables you're interested in.

For example:

```
SQL> select c.table_name, c.column_name, c.data_type, s.num_distinct
  2  from all_tab_columns c join all_tab_col_statistics s on
  3    s.table_name = c.table_name and s.column_name = c.column_name
  4  where c.table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
  5    and c.data_type in ('NUMBER', 'VARCHAR2')
  6  order by c.table_name, c.column_name;

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE       NUM_DISTINCT
---------- --------------- --------------- ------------
DEPT       DEPTNO          NUMBER                     4
DEPT       DNAME           VARCHAR2                   4
DEPT       LOC             VARCHAR2                   4
EMP        COMM            NUMBER                     4
EMP        DEPTNO          NUMBER                     3
EMP        EMPNO           NUMBER                    14
EMP        ENAME           VARCHAR2                  14
EMP        JOB             VARCHAR2                   5
EMP        MGR             NUMBER                     6
EMP        SAL             NUMBER                    12

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to select only columns that have the highest `NUM_DISTINCT` values per each table, use current query as a CTE (Common Table Expression a.k.a. the WITH factoring clause), analytical function (such as `RANK`) to find the one(s) you're interested in. Something like this:

```
SQL> with data as
  2    (select c.table_name, c.column_name, c.data_type, s.num_distinct,
  3            --
  4            rank() over (partition by c.table_name order by s.num_distinct desc) rnk
  5       from all_tab_columns c join all_tab_col_statistics s on
  6         s.table_name = c.table_name and s.column_name = c.column_name
  7       where c.table_name in ('EMP', 'DEPT')
  8         and c.data_type in ('NUMBER', 'VARCHAR2')
  9    )
 10  select table_name, column_name, data_type, num_distinct
 11  from data
 12  where rnk = 1;

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE       NUM_DISTINCT
---------- --------------- --------------- ------------
DEPT       LOC             VARCHAR2                   4
DEPT       DNAME           VARCHAR2                   4
DEPT       DEPTNO          NUMBER                     4
EMP        ENAME           VARCHAR2                  14
EMP        EMPNO           NUMBER                    14

SQL>
```

It says that

- in table DEPT, there are 3 columns that share the same MAX value (4)
- in table EMP, there are 2 such columns (MAX value = 14)

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. I was wondering if it would be possible to also apply this query to multiple tables at the same time (maybe 5 or 10)? For example, instead of just 'EMP', I'd like to potentially be able to also run the query on 'EMP2', 'EMP3', 'EMP4', 'EMP5" at once. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: You're welcome. For multiple tables, you could use IN. I modified my answer to include that option; have a look, please.

Comment: So actually I believe what this does is state the column name and data type for the column that has the max amount of distinct values BETWEEN both tables. Instead I want to state the column name and data type that has the max amount of distinct values for EACH table. Sorry for not clarifying. How would I do this?

Comment: I added some more code. See if that answers your question.